# I must know all the facts. I cannot help you otherwise

Tags: phrases, word-usage

I must know all the facts. I cannot help you otherwise. 
Combine this sentence into complex sentence. 
I have no idea how to combine?

Comment: Unless I know all the facts, I cannot help you?

Comment: Sir, Where is otherwise?

Comment: The meaning of otherwise in the first example is contained in the word "unless" in the second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with this exercise, but if you need it to contain all the source words, you could say:

I must know all the facts, otherwise I cannot help you.

Comment: If you don't want to change the word order at all, you can say `I must know all the facts; I cannot help you otherwise.`